# SQL Field set based on another field

Tags: sql, case, procedure

In my table I have a field called AMT that for import from excel purposes is a char(10). The field is either a dollar amount separated by commas or MM+.  I want to update a new field called AMTBigint that converts this field to a bigint (either the dollar amount or 5000001 for MM+) I have the procedure:

```
USE FI_external_trades;
GO
SELECT  *, case
     WHEN AMT = 'MM+' THEN 5000001
     ELSE cast(replace(AMT, ',' , '') as integer)
  END AS AMTBigint
  From FI_ex_data;
GO
```

The output values are what I want but they create a duplicate field called AMTBigint.  I have tried using set instead but was unable to get the correct syntax.  Advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Update the column of the table with your expected result. So if the case you have written provides the data that you want, then you should do the following. This will update each row's AMTBigint with the result of the case statement.

```
UPDATE FI_ex_data
SET AMTBigint = case
     WHEN AMT = 'MM+' THEN 5000001
     ELSE cast(replace(AMT, ',' , '') as integer)
  END
```